# Choose between unwind segue, dismiss and popViewController to "close" current view controller

Tags: ios, swift

For the current navigation pattern

> A -> B -> C

My understanding is, if we want to go back directly to A from C, using unwind segue will be the most appropriate way.

```
// Execute this code in C
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToA", sender: self)
```

---

But, however, what about a simple navigation pattern?

> A -> B

There are total 3 ways, to go back to A from B

1. `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToA", sender: self)`
2. `self.dismiss()` (Without navigation controller)
3. `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` (With navigation controller)

May I know, how can we choose one another? Is there any reason to still use unwind segue, in such simple case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of the unwind segue is that it is agnostic about how we got here. It does the right thing automatically:

• If we got here by pushing, the unwind segue pops.

• If we got here by presenting, the unwind segue dismisses.

Thus even for a single step backward, it is powerful.

Moreover, unlike calling pop or dismiss, an unwind segue is a *segue*. Thus it can be triggered by a button tap with no code; and `prepare(forSegue:)` works so you can hand info backwards along the hierarchy.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, segue enable us to correctly "exit" from current view controller, regardless how this current view controller is being shown at the first place. Hence, we should prefer unwind segue, over `dismiss` and `popViewController`?

Comment: I do not say “should”. That is a matter of opinion. Choosing is up to you. I merely show you the unwind segue’s special powers even in the simple A -> B situation. You decide.

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding is, if we want to go back directly to A from C, using
> unwind segue will be the most appropriate way.

I guess you meant directly from C to A.

**Unwind segue:** Allows you to jump to a specific ViewController in ViewController hierarchy (including the immediate preceding one) while destroying the other view controller in between (obviously assuming in between viewcontrollers can be deallocated), So in your case when you jump from C to A, not just C but B will also be deallocated when segue finishes

**Pros:**

1. Provides a clean and neat way to jump to any specific ViewConroller in hierarchy without much hassle.
2. You can get hold of view controller being dismissed using `prepareForSegue` and can avoid writing protocol/delegate or closure between source and destination view controller (which can be very cumbersome if there are multiple ViewControllers in between)

**Cons:**

1. Too closely bound between Source and Destination ViewController and will be cumbersome to manage as project grows in size and adds more n more number of ViewControllers and flows between them

In almost all of the real world apps that I have been part of I realized that Segue's in general becomes unusable when complex flow between ViewController increases

**self.dismiss()**

Dismisses the `ViewController` presented by it (self) This statement will work and make sense only if you have ViewControllers presented over it `modally` not `pushed`. If the `presentedViewController` has in-turn presented multiple child View controllers on top of it dismissing the parent ViewController will also dismiss all child View controller

**self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)**

As the name suggests, it pops the top most ViewController from the current navigation stack, This statement will work and make sense only if you have navigation controller embedded and have pushed one or more child ViewController to its stack

I am not gonna compare these 3 statements because `self.dismiss()` and `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` are not the same, though their end product is destroying the destination view controller they are intended for complete different reasons.

One dismisses the modally presented ViewController where as pop will pop the ViewController pushed to navigation stack. You cant use them interchangeably.

Also you usually use `self.dismiss()` and `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` either as individual statement or sometimes in combination to achieve the desired navigation which probably you can achieve using `Unwind segue` as well.

> Is there any reason to still use unwind segue, in such simple case?

That depends on your use case and preferences, what I can answer certainly is can you use unwind segue, in such simple case? Answer is yes, should you use it depends,

1. Are you okay with close coupling of Source and Destination ViewController ( A and C?) What if tomorrow you have to jump from ViewController D to A? Are you okay with dragging another segue? handling these conditions in `prepareForSegue`? Are you okay with trading the code reusability and loose coupling for the ease of achieving the intended navigation? etc etc

**May I know, how can we choose one another?**

1. Do you have one or more ViewController presented modally over your ViewController? Use `self.dismiss()`
2. Do you have a multiple child View controller pushed to your navigation stack and you wanna pop them? use `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`
3. If you have a complicated hierarchy where you have multiple VCs pushed and presented, you will probably have to use combinations of `dismiss` and `popViewController` to reach the specific view controller of your interest
4. Though, all the 3 points can be easily achieved by using unwind segue, you can use unwind segue,  if your use case is not that complicated and you know that there will be a finite combination of ViewController hierarchy possible, go for unwind segue.

Answer (score 0):

Not recommend using segue, it's difficult to maintain and using.

Talking about 2 ways to make view controller back to another.

First, u need to check which way u'r using,

1. ViewController Presenting
2. NavigationViewController Pushing

---

2 Ways to solve:

1. ViewController Presenting:

call dismiss method

```
 self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

2. NavigationViewController Pushing:

call navigation pop up method,

```
 self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

or choose destination view controller to pop,

```
if let vc = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.last(where: { $0.isKind(of: DestinationViewController.self) }) {
    popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```